# With Azure App Service Easy Auth + Azure AD B2C is it possible to secure a single Web API and have multiple native apps consume it?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

We have a Web API intended to serve multiple business partners, each of which will be customizing a white label version of our native app client.

We also have a Web API offering common functions to different apps.

We would like to use AD B2C as the identity and auth system, but cannot see how or if it is possible to use AD B2C to secure a common API for multiple apps. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to your partners usig the account login-in. If you expected that the partners login-in using the consumer account or local account in the Azure AD B2C you own, the answer is yes.

The Azure AD B2C supports the **Access Tokens** from March 23, 2017(refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-ad-b2c-access-tokens-now-in-public-preview/)). And it supports many types of clients, including web apps, desktop and mobile apps, single page apps, server-side daemons, and other web APIs.

It is same to develop an web API server for one native app or multiples apps, you only need to register the multiple apps in your B2C tenant. More detail about acquring the access token for the Azure AD B2C, you can refer the link below:

[Azure Active Directory B2C: OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code)

Comment: OK thanks I will check and verify this, but if it is true then the majority of B2C MS documentation needs updating - I found explicit warnings that multiple native apps consuming a single API are not supported by B2C. Having said that, the March 23 2017 date is very recent, so I will check what you write and upvote accordingly

Comment: This is GA or public preview?

Comment: This feature is in public preview. And please feel free to let me know if you still have the problem about this issue. In-addition, if you have any feedback about the document, you can submit the feedback from the bottom of the document page through **Is this page helpful**.

Comment: Thanks Fei Xue, I am going to review this option in detail