# B2C app scopes not going to API app

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I have separate UI web app from the API web app. Both registered as applications in B2C. I've enabled Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization (easy auth) on the UI web app, and configured the API web app to use JwtBearer middleware to authenticate calls to API.

This seems to work, but I have trouble getting scopes through to the API web app. I have published the scopes in the API app, and configured the UI app to have access to these scopes.

I've tried different login URL options, e.g., `https://myUIapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad?p=b2c_1a_mysigninpolicy&scope=openid+https://myb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/api/company.read&post_login_redirect_uri=/app`

and ensured that the API apps "App ID URI" (in B2C app settings) is indeed "api", while the scope name is `company.read`. Still after successful authentication, when going to `/.auth/me`, I do not see the scope, I do see other claims just fine.

Where should I start looking into pointers on this?

**UPDATE**

I've determined how I end up in this situation, but it is still unclear why:

1. User authenticates starting with URL such as: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/mydevb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_signin&client_id=UIAPP_GUID&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FUIAPP.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&scope=openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fmydevb2c.onmicrosoft.com%2Fapi%2Fcompany.write%20https%3A%2F%2Fmydevb2c.onmicrosoft.com%2Fapi%2Fcompany.read&response_type=id_token%20token&prompt=login`
2. After successful authentication, user is redirected to `https://UIAPP.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`, as defined, BUT is  immediately redirected back to authentication system with default scope set "openid+profile+email", i.e. URL such as `https://login.microsoftonline.com/mydevb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FUIAPP.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=UIAPP_GUID&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&p=b2c_1a_signinsuomifi&nonce=somenonce&state=redir%3D%252Fapp`

If I take the access_token from the first callback to `/.auth/login/aad/callback` it contains the requested scopes, but second authentication callback obviously doesn't as it requests default scope set.

Do I perhaps need to start the easy auth login process via `.auth/login/aad` in order for it to accept the callback as well?

**UPDATE 2**

Yes, need to start the process via `.auth/login/aad`: when using login URL such as `https://myUIapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad?p=B2C_1A_signin&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FmyUIapp.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&scope=openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fmydevb2c.onmicrosoft.com%2Fapi%2Fcompany.write%20https%3A%2F%2Fmydevb2c.onmicrosoft.com%2Fapi%2Fcompany.read&response_type=id_token%20token&prompt=login&post_login_redirect_uri=/app` removes the second authentication redirect.

The question now is, why do I only see the **id_token** in `.auth/me` and not the **access_token** that is clearly returned to the `.auth/login/aad/callback`? And ultimately: how come using the access_token as Bearer token, I still cannot query the easy auth secured API, but get error `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`? I have followed steps in [Azure client app accessing Azure api secured by AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646823/azure-client-app-accessing-azure-api-secured-by-ad).

If I switch off easy auth, and use the JwtBearer middleware in my API, it works fine.

Comment: [This sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/Controllers/TasksController.cs#L39) demonstrates how to get an access token using the auth code flow.

Comment: Thanks, I already get the access_token during auth process, but having hard time getting hold of it, any ideas?

Comment: seems like [eash auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication) is a Azure AD thing not a Azure AD B2C thing...

Comment: No, you're thinking of "easy oauth" (at least that's what the edited link https://easyauth.azurewebsites.net refers to). "easy auth" is just what the Azure App Authentication is/was referred to in some cases (https://cgillum.tech/category/easy-auth/). There are bits and pieces here and there indicating it would work with this full scenario, but nothing really concrete.

Comment: One example of these vague posts indicating it would be possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539757/with-azure-app-service-easy-auth-azure-ad-b2c-is-it-possible-to-secure-a-singl

Comment: Gotcha, did some more research, easy auth is a azure app services thing.  East auth is easy oauth, same thing.  See url name and YouTube video name.  Seems like this is what the devs called it but didn’t become the official name of this feature.